# How to select one from duplicate tag in page in java in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver and I have number of items on a page and each item on page is a separate form type.

I have saved all of these form elements in a list and I am iterating over every item in an attempt to get the name of the element by using the "alt" attribute.

However when I try to get the "name" attribute from the input element it is always returning the first input tag found on that page, not the name attribute of the element I have currently selected.

The syntax I am using is:

```
((Webdriver imgtags.get(i)).findelement(By.xpath("//input[@name='qty']")).sendKeys ("100");
```

I have also tried to get the id from the tag by using:

```
((Webdriver imgtags.get(i)).getAttribute("id");
```

It's returning a blank value, but it should return the value of the id attribute in that input tag.

I also tried to get the id by using .bytagname but as id is an attribute it is not accessible

Comment: You need to post more code. Nothing you are showing should be an issue. Post the relevant HTML and then an [mcve] that we can run to see the issue.

Comment: I disagree, the Xpath he is using will definitely cause an issue because it will search the entire DOM rather than the tree under the element he has extracted from the List.  Showing an HTML structure as well would help us provide more accurate answers, but I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(driver) findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(local-name(), 'input') and contains(@name, 'qty')]")).sendKeys("100");
```

To answer the comment by @rrd: to be honest, I have no idea why OP uses ((Webdriver imgtags.get(i)). I don't know what that is. Normally, I just use  driver.findElement[...]

Hoping that he knows what works in his framework :D

Comment: The answer may very well be correct, but perhaps you could explain why 'driver' instead of 'Webdriver' for the OP, and perhaps why he doesn't need imgtags?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, you can't cast into a variable, you cast into a type.  Based on the OP's question imgtags is a List of unknown Type, hence why after extracting an element from the list it needs to be cast into type WebDriver

Answer (score -1):

Selenium Xpath handling is not fully compliant and it does not always treat // as a synonym of descendant-or-self.

Instead try tweaking your code to use the following Xpath:

```
 ((Webdriver imgtags.get(i)).findElement(By.xpath("./descendant-or-self::input[@name='qty']")).sendKeys("100");
```

This will base your search off the currently selected WebElement and then look for any descendants that have a name attribute with a value of "qty".

I would also suggest storing your imgtags array as an array of WebElement e.g.

```
List<WebElement> imgtags = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is a much better idea than casting to WebDriver to be able to use .findElement().  This will cause you problems at some point in the future.

Comment: But I cannot use descendents as appcation is very unstable this time

Comment: As noted above // means descendant-or-self so you are already using descendants.  It would probably help if you supplied some HTML because this comment makes your question less clear

Comment: Couldn't you just simplify to `((Webdriver imgtags.get(i)).findElement(By.xpath("./input[@name='qty']")).sendKeys("100");` and not bring descendants into it?

Comment: That all depends upon the structure of the HTML, which is currently unknown.  If the input element is a child of the element stored in the array that would work.  At the end of the day the OP originally tried to use descendant-or-self, the problem is that Selenium doesn't always treat // in the way it should

Comment: Let me explain the tree .there is a div tag under that there is form under this there is a div tag that is container inside this tag there is a input tag that id in it. In a one page there are number of form tags and each tag has id inside it. I have saved these form tags in List and then tried to get id attribute value from this

Comment: In that case my answer still stands, you need to use descendant-or-self as that will start at the form tag and work its way down the tree until it finds an input element with the correct attribute.  Have you tried my solution?